Movie where bookworm is last surviving human, then eyeglasses break
It was a black-and-white film where a guy survives by hiding in a vault in a bank.
When he comes out everything is in ruins, but some of the books from the library are not.
He says, 

"Hello? W-Where is everybody? I...I'm the only human left. Well, at least I have my books."

(With some books, he walks down some steps and then reaches for a book.  His glasses fall and the lenses smash to pieces.  He starts to panic not scream.)

"NO, NO THA.. THAT... THAT'S NOT FAIR THATS NOT FAIR. That's not fair."  

(Begins to cry.)  

"There was time now." 

And then we are shown some aliens with antennas (which the people who came up with the stuff used TV antennas).

I would suggest changing the title of this question to something more descriptive of the film.  Otherwise every 'Identify this Movie' question would have near identical titles.

This was also featured in, I think, one of the Simpson's episodes (or it might be Futurama). ISTR his glasses break and then his eyes fall out etc.

Some interpunction would help, these sentences are a pain in the azz to read.

@Stefan It was the Futurama episode "A Head in the Polls".  After his eyes fall out, he says, "Lucky I know how to read Braille."  Then his hands fall off.

@FredH, that's the one!

Possible duplicate of Movie about the last man on Earth who loses his glasses and can't read books

That sounds exactly like the famous Twilight Zone episode "Time Enough at Last".  According to Wikipedia, the final speech is

That's not fair. That's not fair at all. There was time now. There was all the time I needed...! That's not fair!


It is thank you

@Bulldog7667 If you find this answer helpful consider accepting it

Burgess Merideth played the bookworm.  One of my favorite episodes.
